# Exclude some folders and files from any process in gradle

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

I have a small project for Android and try to add some source folders.
Using something like this works:

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../some-source-folder/'
}
```

I also added this in my iml file:

```
<content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../some-source-folder">
  <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../some-source-folder" isTestSource="false" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/../../some-source-folder/sub-folder" />
</content>
```

The problem now is, that I really need to exclude some of the subfolders of my source folder 'some-source-folder'
Using excludeFolder in my iml file means the sub folder are not displayed in my Android stdio. But they still will be compiled using gradle.

But nothing works in my gradle file to exclude some of the subfolders with java files which shall not be compiled!

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../some-source-folder/'
    main {
        java {
            exclude ('../../some-source-folder/some-subfolder', '../../some-source-folder/another-subfolder')

        }
    }
 }
```

does not work.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += '../../some-source-folder/'
    exclude '../../some-source-folder/some-subfolder'
    exclude '../../some-source-folder/another-subfolder'
 }
```

does not work either.

If I try to add something with excludes in a comple closure e.g.

```
compile {
     exclude '../../some-source-folder/some-subfolder'
}
```

I get an error

**Gradle sync failed: Could not find method compile() for arguments [build_....]**

I get similiar errors using

```
 excludes '...'
```

or

```
 exclude = ['....', '....', '....']
```

will lead to the errors:

**Gradle sync failed: Could not find method excludes() for arguments ...**

and

**Gradle sync failed: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashSet.getAt() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values:**

Is there an easy way to add any source folder to a project in Android Studio and excluding couple of sub folders or/and source files?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using android studio and the android project structure is a bit different, you should use [Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html) and configure a product flavor. Foreach build variant you can configure a source set.

For instance:

```
src/demoDebug/ (build variant source set)
src/debug/ (build type source set)
src/demo/ (product flavor source set)
src/main/ (main source set)
```

Check it here: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html#sourcesets

Comment: Thanks Sandro. I finally find the reason why this had not worked. I need to exclude the path using the relative path to the source dir. Unfortunately I need to override classes. So I cannot use flavors because flavors use always different package names.